# How to set custom path to preload.swf in gaia framework?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, gaia

How can I set custom path to prealod.swf in gaia framework? I need this because the index.html file generated by gaia and all the swfs are located in different directories. I have set full path to all the swf files but preload.swf because I can't find the appropriate parameter anywhere. Now I get 404 error message for preload.swf in consolo.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the path in the `preloader` attribute of your `site` node in your site's xml file.

Example:

```
<site title="My Super Site: %PAGE%" preloader="path/to/preloader/swf.swf">
```

[This is a list for all the customizations available for the site xml.](http://www.gaiaflashframework.com/wiki/index.php?title=Site_XML)